# Load attribute from external page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#result").load("file.html *HERE*");
});
```

In *HERE* I want search only the elements with "fontsize:20pt". Is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly, no. You can only select by CSS rules (eg id, class, attribute etc). You would need to grab all the whole page and `filter()` the elements to find those with the matching `font-size` set. Alternatively if you know the elements you want, add a class to them and use that class to target them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [specs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

If there is a [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that can be created for your request, the answer is yes.

```
$("#result").load("file.html .pt20"); // if there's a class on the object
```

If not, you can extract the elements after if you have a way to identify them - note we need to use another ajax method - here `$.get`is used:

[*DEMO*](http://plungjan.name/SO/loadptonly.html)

```
$(function() {
  $.get("filept.html",function(data) {
     $(data).find("p").each(function() {
       var fs = $(this).css("font-size"); // note: "20pt" or 26.nnn for computed size
       if (parseInt($(this).css("font-size"),10) == 20) {
         $("#result").append($(this));
       }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: `load()` will still append all the content. Should use other ajax method, e.g `$.get()`

Comment: It will always load all the content and then filter on the selector. If you do not want that, you need a proxy to read the file and extract

Comment: I was talking about the second method, not using `selector`

Comment: If i Use this, console.log find a wrong in the 4th line: Unexpected token }

Comment: I missed a quote (thanks for the edit) and added brackets for you

Comment: @A.Wolff - thanks - updated the second example to use `$.get`

Comment: oh, sure. Thanks! And why do you change 18pt for 26?

Comment: @OscarLT Because `.css()` returns computed style which is always in pixel **but** can vary. BTW, that's why you would have better to target a class or any other attribute but not a stylized one

Comment: sorry again, but now console says "data.find is not a function", i don't understand it.